# How to rename a SQLite table with dplyr?

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I want to change the name of a SQLite table using R/dplyr.

From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html), it looks like (at first glance) it should be just:

```
db <- src_sqlite("db/path.sqlite", create = TRUE)
mtcars %>% add_rownames() %>% rename(car = rowname) -> mtcars2
copy_to(db, mtcars2, indexes = list("car"))
q <- "ALTER TABLE mtcars2 RENAME TO mtcars3"
tbl(db, sql(q))
```

However, this gives an error. I thought maybe it was the missing semi-colon, but I get the same error in either case.

```
 Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement) (from #4) : 
  error in statement: near "ALTER": syntax error
```

The top of the traceback shows:

```
21: .Call(rsqlite_query_send, con@Id, as.character(statement), bind.data)
20: sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement)
19: .local(conn, statement, ...)
18: DBI::dbSendQuery(con, build_sql("SELECT * FROM ", sql))
17: DBI::dbSendQuery(con, build_sql("SELECT * FROM ", sql))
```

Is there a way to change the table name relying on the connection generated by src_sqlite, or do I have to close this connection and open another connection using RSQLite/DBI directly? For my application, I'd much prefer the former.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this using `DBI` you can use `DBI:::dbSendQuery(db$con, sql(q))`. By using `db$con`, you do not need to open another connection.